# Android show img in webview from app data dir

Tags: android

I just saved an image to: `App.getContext().filesDir`

Now I want to load the image in a html to a webview like this:

```
<img src="/data/user/0/com.asd.myappname/files/MyAppName/htmlimgs/first.jpg" />
```

the image is broken like here. why?

[image]

but the img is on the folder...

Comment: What do you mean *the image is broken* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code in kotlin (Ref from Sana answer)

You can write this code and try,

```
web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true)
```

( OR )

```
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/data/user/0/com.asd.myappname/files/MyAppName/htmlimgs/first.jpg")
val imgView = this.findViewById(R.id.imgViewId) as ImageView
imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
val bitmap = YOUR_BITMAP
val html = "<html><body><img src='{IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER}' /></body> </html>"
val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)
val byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
val imgageBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT)
val image = "data:image/png;base64," + imgageBase64
html = html.replace("{IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER}", image)
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "")
```

Comment: base64 is saved my day! an edit: PNG is very slow, I changed to JPEG, and 75 compress

Comment: time is precious, that's great

Answer (score 1):

You can write this code and try,

```
web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

OR :

Get the bitmap of the images and convert to base64 encoded image and the show them to the WebView like this,

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/data/user/0/com.asd.myappname/files/MyAppName/htmlimgs/first.jpg");

ImageView imgView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imgViewId);

imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

// Desired Bitmap and the html code, where you want to place it
 Bitmap bitmap = YOUR_BITMAP;
 String html="<html><body><img src='{IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER}' /></body>  </html>";

// Convert bitmap to Base64 encoded image for web

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
 byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
 String imgageBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
 String image = "data:image/png;base64," + imgageBase64;

// Use image for the img src parameter in your html and load to webview
html = html.replace("{IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER}", image);
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

Try this.

Comment: Sorry but my html comes from a room table, and my imgs saved to my app's data folder. So I need to do in this way!